# Grouping header column from specific key values in list of dicts to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to group headers by specific key value for a list of dicts

```
  my lists = [

      {'rank': 2, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume': 456677, 'asin': 'B01MG0ORBL','parent': parent1
      },
      {'rank': 18, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume': 456677, 'asin': 'B0735C9RDZ','parent': parent1'
      },
      {'rank': 21, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume': 456677, 'asin': 'B07FPVR858','parent': 'parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 126, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume':   , 'asin': 'B01MG0ORBL','parent': parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 128, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume': 456677, 'asin': 'B0735C9RDZ','parent': parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 136, 'keyword_name': 'mens wallet', 'volume': 456677, 'asin': 'B07FPVR858','parent': parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 19, 'keyword_name': 'leather wallets', 'volume': , 'asin': 'B0735C9RDZ','parent': parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 10, 'keyword_name': 'wallets for men', 'volume': 566, 'asin': 'B07FPVR858','parent': parent2'
      },
      {'rank': 16, 'keyword_name': 'wallets for men', 'volume': 566, 'asin': 'B0735C9RDZ','parent': parent2'
      },
  ]
```

// Create dataframe and pivoting with lists

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(my_lists)

  df = df.pivot_table(index=['keyword_name','volume'], 
                columns='asin', 
                values='rank', 
                aggfunc=list)
   print (df)
   asin                   B01MG0ORBL B0735C9RDZ B07FPVR858
   keyword_name    volume                                 
   leather wallets 23            NaN       [19]        NaN
   mens wallet     456677   [2, 126]  [18, 128]  [21, 136]
   wallets for men 566           NaN       [16]       [10]
```

But what I need to achieve is to group header columns by key(parent) value where each asin inside each dict belongs to parent(key), like

```
                                  parent1             parent2             parent3
   asin                   B01MG0ORBL B0735C9RDZ B07FPVR858 xxxxxxxxx  xxxxx   xxxx  xxx
   keyword_name    volume                                 
   leather wallets 23            NaN       [19]        NaN
   mens wallet     456677   [2, 126]  [18, 128]  [21, 136]
   wallets for men 566           NaN       [16]       [10]
```

Example desired output

[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the problem's description and the expected result presented do not really match each other. If I understood it right, you need a multindex column?

Then simply (note that `parent` was added to the list of `columns` at the first place):

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['keyword_name', 'volume'],
                     columns=['parent', 'asin'],
                     values='rank',
                     aggfunc=list)

print(df2.columns)

MultiIndex([('parent1', 'B01MG0ORBL'),
            ('parent1', 'B0735C9RDZ'),
            ('parent2', 'B0735C9RDZ'),
            ('parent2', 'B07FPVR858')],
           names=['parent', 'asin'])
```

PS. I could not reproduce your output with the shared data.